# How do you connect a 1 to many table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a ASP.NET Core project that has these two tables: City and Country.

```
public class City 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CityName{ get; set; }
    public string Region{ get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CountryName{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Continent{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Capital{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int NumberOfPeople{ get; set; }
}
```

A city class inherits a country foreign key and 1 country can have more than one city i.e 1-(0..M). They both come from the same `DbContext`.
I want to be able to click on the details page on the index page of "Countries"(display all the countries, their attributes and options)
so that it show the country info and all the cities of that country but I can't figure out how to connect the two tables via the `DbContext`.

How do I pass a model  that loads the Country info with the specific id and all the cities inside to the Details View

Comment: What's exactly the problem? The posted model doesn't have any error, so it is not clear what your question is

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto How do I pass a model  that load the Country info with the specific id  of the Country and all The Cities inside it into the details view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include all `City`s in a `Country`, you will need to add a navigational property from `Country` to `City` (the other part of the already configured relationship):

```
public class Country
{
    ...
    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to perform a single database query to bring all the results without having to do manual joins.
You can then use this as:

```
var country = await context.Countries
    .Include(x => x.Cities)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.ID == someId);
```

You can use the non-`Async` versions of the query executors, but given that you are on an ASP.NET Core app, I'd recommend against that.

Comment: I love you. Do you have any good sites/docs on how to read related data and navigational properties?

Comment: @King23 The Microsoft Docs is a great place for tutorials, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have been using the MVC tutorial doc but they skip half of the explanation in the modeling part

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it.

First, you should declare your classes, such as:

```
public class City 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CityName{ get; set; }

    public string Region{ get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CountryName{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Continent{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Capital{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NumberOfPeople{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Second, you should configure the relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(Modelbuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Cities)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Country)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use attributes for the fields:

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CityName{ get; set; }
    public string Region{ get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CountryName{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Continent{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Capital{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NumberOfPeople{ get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Country")]
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why use attributes if EF can do it by convention?

Comment: Code clarity? I find it's much easier to tell what's going on with the attributes and gets you used to it in a situation when you can't use the convention (e.g. working with a legacy DB).

Comment: No, with attributes you need to see the definition of each class to see what's going on, with conventions you can know by the name. When working with legacy DBs it's useful though

Comment: That's not always true though. You could have a column called Id and another column which is decorated with the Key attribute (bad design) - to be sure you always have to look at the class or the model.

Comment: "which is decorated with the Key attribute" that proves my point. You are using DataAnnotation not convention over configuration

Comment: What does the  [InverseProperty("Country")] do ?

Comment: Gives the navigation property in the referred to class. But as @CamiloTerevinto says it isn'y always necessary.